# Multiple DLL Resource Management

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, dll, mfc

I have an existing MFC product and am planning on supporting a couple of other national languages thru the use of resource-only DLLs. I've read a number of articles and tutorials on how to go about this, but admit that I don't have a lot of in-depth knowledge of Windows resources (mostly just use VS 2008's graphical interface).

The major area that I am trying to understand is that it seems like all of the resource source files (i.e., resource.rc) for these  DLLs -- and the main program -- should be sharing the same copy of resource.h. After all, all those IDD_xxx values have to be consistent, and it seems like making updates to the resources would be even more complicated by having to keep multiple resource.h files in sync!

So am I correct on this, and does anyone have any tips for how to best implement this? Should I modify resource.rc in the DLL projects to point to the "master" resource.h in the main program directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the same resource.h file for sure.

One way is to just copy the resources you need to be translated into the the new resource project--stuff like menus, strings, dialogs. Bitmaps and icons probably don't need to be translated unless you put some text on them that is language specific.  If you know your localse, at program startup you can call AfxSetResourceHandle() with the resource DLL you manually load.

Another way to approach the problem if you have a multitude of DLLs and EXEs is to use binary resource editing tools. What they do is create token files from your resources.  Your translators edit the token file with the binary editing tool.  When all is done, you run a tool to apply the translation to the binaries. Basically, you don't distribute resource DLLs, but distribute different versions of your DLLs for each language. The tools are smart enough so that if you make a change like add a string or dialog, it will get picked up and your translator can see that he needs to translate something new. The previously translated work will be saved in the token files. This is how we do it at my shop. We used to use Microsoft's Localization Resource toolkit. I don't know if we still use it or not since it is somebody else's responsibility now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the MSDN article ID 198846 a good starting point for sharing of resources via a dll, though it does need updating for newer versions of visual studio, it was quite easy to follow and understand.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198846